# Cardinal sine envelop

Tags: trigonometry, differential-geometry, curves

I am looking for an envelope of the function $t\mapsto \mbox{sinc}^2(t)$, or at least an approximation of such an envelope. Is there a known envelope function?

Here's an illustration of $\mbox{sinc}^2(t) = \frac{\sin^2(\pi t)}{(\pi t)^2}$ (blue), and of one of its envelopes (red), which I drew by hand.

[image: sinc2 function and envelope]

More generally, I was wondering, how does one calculate an envelope?

Comment: The function $1/\pi^2t^2$ is an envelope (probably not the one you are dreaming of).

Comment: @FlorianT: Did you mean  one smoth and continuous envelope?

Comment: yes, I was dreaming of such an envelope!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An envelope is defined for a parametric family of functions and not for a single member. It is obtained by eliminating the parameter between the function equation and that obtained by differentiating over the parameter.

For example, consider the family

$$y=\frac{\sin^2\lambda t}{t^2}.$$ The aformentioned derivative is

$$0=\frac2t\sin\lambda t\cos\lambda t,$$ which implies $\sin^2\lambda t=0$ or $1$.

Hence the two envelopes

$$y=\frac1{t^2},\\y=0.$$

Comment: That's not exactly the answer I expected, I had rather [this in mind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Envelope_(waves)), but that's because I didn't know the exact definition of an envelope in mathematics... But now I do, and as we're here in the maths kingdom, that's an accepted answer!

Comment: @FlorianT: I have tried to find a parametric family that would yield your red curve, but that seems uneasy.

Answer (score 0):

Only a single parameter curve can have a unique envelope obtained by $ c, p$ discriminant  methods.

Your sketch includes a parameter which you have not identified, but implied.

For example a sine curve needs to be associted with parameter $c$ in $ y= A \sin c x,  $ so that an elimination of parameter $c$ leads to envelope $y=\pm A.$

Following example is given for the curve $$ y=\frac{ \sin cx} {x},$$ the sinc squared curve could follow with the same procedure.

By partial differentition with $c$ one obtains

$$ \cos cx = 0 , \quad \sin cx  = \pm 1, \rightarrow \, y=\frac{\pm1}{x} $$  which are hyperbolae curves are exactly sketched below.

[image]

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, by partial differentition with $c$ you obtain $0=cos(cx)$ and not $tan(cx)=cx$. And thus you obtain the $1/x$ function by eliminating the parameter $c$. And that seems to be confirmed by your drawing: the two envelopes you drew seem to be really close to $\pm1/x$.

Comment: Thanks for the drawing, which made me understand better what exactly an envelope is.